# The index.html file has different width and height than other pages [but it should]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a simple static page where I've (about,contact etc.).
The problem is that index.html page has different width and height(body) comparing to others pages. But I set one size for all pages and it works on them - except index.html

First thought - I messed with CSS and tried to find class or id which could change the css of my index.html - NOPE.
Then i just copied whole content from about.html and paste it to index.html and again the size was wrong.
Finally i change the name of index.html on home.html and after that the width and height was CORRECT.
So the problem was not in content of html but in filename. 
I searched through whole my work directory if some css has not affecting "index.html" name , but without effect.

Any tip where I can fix this problem?

[I'm using boostrap]

Comment: Include some code please

Comment: Without your codes no one can help you..

Comment: When i uploaded web-page on server - everything was looking okay. The bug/error only occur locally at my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't exactly say without any code, but i had experienced a similar issue before, so it might help.

It might be a browser issue. Try to see the index.html in different web browsers. If you ever used the Zoom option in your browser while on index.html, it will automatically display your index.html with the last time Zoom preferences, so the page will appear different from what it should look according to the CSS.

Try cleaning cache and then try opening the index.html
that's all that could be told without any code. Please upload the code if you still face the problem.